# Notifydatasetchanged() is causing blinking within child recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nested, swipe

I am having an extremely hard time trying to disable animations for a nested recyclerview whenever the parent recyclerview calls ondatasetchanged(). So some context a recyclerview that holds tinder-like swap cards and a nested recyclerview within each card to scroll through user images. After every swipe ondatasetchanged is called and causing a bad flickering within the nested recyclerview. I  have tried to disabled the animations from both parent and child recyclerviews and pretty much anything I can think of at this point. The code below is my view holder for each card.

```
 public class CardStackHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnItemSwipePercentageListener {
    ImageButton profileInfoBtn;
    RecyclerView images_recyclerView;
    PagerSnapHelper snapHelper;
    ProfileImagesAdapter imagesAdapter;
    String profileName;
    TextView nameBox;
    TextView ageBox;
    TextView workBox;
    List<String> list;


    public CardStackHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        profileInfoBtn = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ID_datingRecyclerView_profileInfoBtn);
        profileInfoBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //show profile info dialog
                User_Info_Dialog dialog = User_Info_Dialog.getDialog(mHostId, mCurrentProfile.getGender(), mCurrentProfile.getOrientation(), mCurrentProfile.getInterestedIn(), mCurrentProfile.getIntro(), mCurrentProfile.getStatus());
                dialog.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "");
            }
        });

        nameBox = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ID_datingRecyclerView_profile_name);
        ageBox = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ID_datingRecyclerView_profile_age);
        images_recyclerView = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ID_datingRecyclerView_profileImagesRecyclerView);

        RecyclerView.ItemAnimator animator = images_recyclerView.getItemAnimator();
        ((SimpleItemAnimator) animator).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
        animator.setChangeDuration(0);
        animator.setRemoveDuration(0);

        images_recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext));
        snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
        snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(images_recyclerView);

        workBox = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ID_datingRecyclerView_profile_work);

    }


    public void onBind(Context context, User_Profile profile) {
        getImages(profile.getProfileId());
        profileName = profile.getFirst_name();
        profileName = profileName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + profileName.substring(1);
        nameBox.setText(profileName);
        ageBox.setText(profile.getAge());
        String workStr = profile.getWork();
        workStr = workStr.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + workStr.substring(1);
        workBox.setText(workStr);
        mCurrentProfile = profile;
    }


    public void getImages(String id) {

        mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("profile_pictures").child(id).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    list = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        if (snapshot.hasChild("dating_card_imagePath")) {
                            list.add(snapshot.child("dating_card_imagePath").getValue().toString());
                        }
                    }

                    imagesAdapter = new ProfileImagesAdapter(list);
                    imagesAdapter.setHasStableIds(true);
                    images_recyclerView.setAdapter(imagesAdapter);

                } else {
                    // no images found for profile
                    imagesAdapter = new ProfileImagesAdapter();
                    imagesAdapter.setHasStableIds(true);
                    images_recyclerView.setAdapter(imagesAdapter);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemSwipePercentage(double percentage) {
        //log percentage moved
        //Log.d("Enchanted", Double.toString(percentage));

        if (percentage > -0.20 && percentage < 0.20) {
            swipeResultImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else if (percentage < 0.20) {
            swipeResultImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_swipe_no_like);
            swipeResultImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (percentage > -0.20) {
            swipeResultImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_swipe_like);
            swipeResultImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }


}
```

code below is my adapter

```
//CardStack Adapter
class CardStackAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardStackHolder> {
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    List<User_Profile> profileList;
    RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool ImagePool;


    public CardStackAdapter(Context context, List<User_Profile> list) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        profileList = new ArrayList<>(list);
        ImagePool = new RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool();
    }

    @Override
    public CardStackHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item_dating_profile_card, parent, false);
        return new CardStackHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CardStackHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.images_recyclerView.setRecycledViewPool(ImagePool);
        profileList.get(position).setItemId(holder.getItemId());
        holder.onBind(mContext, profileList.get(position));
    }


    public void removeTopItem() {
        profileList.remove(0);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }


    public void addItemToTop() {
        profileList.add(0, mPreviousProfile);
        notifyItemInserted(0);
    }

    public void updateProfileList(List<User_Profile> p) {
        ImagePool.clear();
        profileList.clear();
        profileList.addAll(p);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return profileList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return profileList.get(position).getItemId();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` inside `removeTopItem()`?
Using `notifyDataSetChanged()` recreate all views again. You can notify recyclerview in which position item removed.

```
public void removeTopItem() {
    profileList.remove(0);
    notifyItemRemoved(0);
}
```

Comment: yes i am aware of how this works and i have tried it using notifyItemRemoved(0) but for some reason that introduces a whole new problem whereas i swipe a card after the first one, it would just flat out stop writing to the database. I am assuming this library am using for the swipe feature is a bit of a mess and i will probably consider replacing it with another one.